# Horizontal centering of div within display:table row

Tags: css, html, centering

I have a layout composed of divs displaying as table, 3 table rows, and up to 5 table cells per row. My problem is twlofold:
1) I can't figure out how to center the table cells within the rows if there are less than five cells in the table., and 
2) I can't figure out how to keep the integrity of the shapes when there are less than 5 in a row.

The number of cells in a row will be variable (between 3 and 5), and  I have to use divs -- I can't use real tables.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/Jaemaz/full/aCboe

Here is the source:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="focus-container">
  <div class="focus-row">
    <div class="focus-element  circle">
      <span class="ng-scope">
        Option A
      </span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element  circle">
        <span class="ng-scope">
          Option B
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element  circle">
        <span class="ng-scope">
          Option C
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element  circle">
        <span class="ng-scope">
          Option D
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element  circle">
        <span class="ng-scope">
          Option E
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="focus-row">
    <div class="focus-element  circle" ng-class="{unknown: unknown, square: square, circle: circle, selected: selected, shouldHaveBeenSelected: shouldHaveBeenSelected, shouldNotHaveBeenSelected: shouldNotHaveBeenSelected}" ng-click="click()" ng-transclude="" focuschoice="" identifier="F" enabled="true">
      <span class="ng-scope">
        Option F
      </span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.focus-container {
width: 560px;
height: auto;
display: table;
background-color: #000;
border-spacing: 15px;
table-layout: fixed;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.focus-row {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: table-row;
}

.focus-element {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
display: table-cell;
color: #fff;
background: #808080;
border: 2px solid #BFBFBF;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Ubuntu", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
max-width: 94px;
}

.focus-element.circle {
-moz-border-radius: 94px;
-webkit-border-radius: 94px;
border-radius: 94px;
}
```

Screen Shot:
[image]

Comment: Do you need to use `display: table-row`? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gkzgj

Comment: I need to use divs as tables, instead of actual tables.

Comment: @user1958534 - why do you need to use `div` as a table? If you have tabular data then you can use a `table` element. If it is just for styling then you can achieve what you want without using `display: table-row` (see the link to the codepen in my previous comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Jojje 's suggestion, the answer lies in creating an extra "inner" level (display:table) within the div structure. Solution is on CodePen here: http://codepen.io/Jaemaz/pen/spbKf

In case Codepen goes away, here is sample HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="focus-container">
  <div class="focus-row">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>ahem</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="focus-row">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>hello</span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>there</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="focus-row">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>what</span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span class="content">is</span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>happening</span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>happening</span>
      </div>
      <div class="focus-element circle">
        <span>happening</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.focus-container {
  width: 560px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.focus-container .focus-row {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #000
}

.focus-container .focus-row .inner {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 110px;
}

.focus-container .focus-row .inner .focus-element {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 94px;
  height: 94px;
  background-color: #009900;
}

.focus-container .focus-row .inner .focus-element span {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: block;
}

.focus-container .focus-row .inner .circle {
  -moz-border-radius: 94px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 94px;
  border-radius: 94px;
  margin: 8px;
```

Comment: it's only arguably better if someone feels like arguing for jsFiddle in that matchup. (I don't). But send the pen link instead of the display link: http://codepen.io/Jaemaz/pen/spbKf

Comment: Late on the reply, but thanks for your feedback  @BrianVanderbusch

Answer (score 1):

Tables won't do that, but tables in table will. 1) Use single-cell rows in outer table and a new table within each cell, and center the inner table within the row. 2) You might use fixed (or some relative) width and height on each cell within inner tables.

ADDED: 
This will work for display:table as well as old-school table. 
Outermost table should only have one cell in each row, and in that cell place the inner table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will this work with display:table within display:table?  What do you mean by single-cell row in table? Can you paste a fiddle or CodePen of the structure?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with CodePen

Comment: Got it @Jojje. Works like a charm. See it action on Codepen here [link](http://cdpn.io/spbKf)

Comment: Would you be so kind to give me a point for the answer ? If you do I will then get some binary cake from SO.